# Property [products] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel

in my app I first retrieve product categories with products, now I want to extract products from product categories but I get the following error:

```
Property [products] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

This is how I get categories first and then products

```
$productCategories = ProductCategory::with('products')->get(); //This works

$products = $productCategories->products; //Then this gives me error
```

Here are my models and migrations:

```
class Product extends FilterableModel
{


    protected $table = 'products';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ProductCategory', 'productcategory_id');
    }
```

```
class ProductCategory extends FilterableModel
{


    protected $table = 'productcategories';


    public function products()
    {
        return $this->HasMany('App\Models\Product', 'productcategory_id');
    }


}
```

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('productcategory_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('productcategory_id')->references('id')->on('productcategories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->text('body')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('isVisible')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('isFeatured')->default(false);
            $table->integer('stock')->default(0);
            $table->decimal('originalPrice', 5,2)->default(0.00);
            $table->decimal('finalPrice', 5,2)->default(0.00);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```
Schema::create('productcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('url')->unique();
            $table->text('body')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->default(config('app.defaultImage'));
            $table->string('icon')->default('fa fa-tag');
            $table->boolean('isVisible')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('isFeatured')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

So, your `$productCategories` variable is a Collection of `ProductCategory` instances.
If you want to get a products of all of them, you need to loopin it:

```
foreach ($productCategories as $productCategory) {
   dump($productCategory->products);
}
```

If you want to get products of one of `productCategory` you need to select it from database:

```
$productCategory = ProductCategory::findOrFail($productCategoryId);
dump($productCategory->products);
```

Hope it helps.